# how to access chrome pdf rendering capability from javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, plugins, google-chrome, rendering-engine

I need to know how to access chrome pdf rendering capability from javascript in chrome (but also firefox etc, now I start with chrome). I want to be able to manage single pages and I am interested in performance. I see that chrome is fast at rendering.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it directly, but there is [js library](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) that allows creating pdf files in javascript which then can be displayed in the browser by using Data URI format.